# Obtaining a certain section from a line in a file (C++)

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

I've spent a lot of time looking online to find a answer for this, but nothing was helping, so I figured I'd post my specific scenario. I have a .txt file (see below), and I am trying to write a routine that just finds a certain chunk of a certain line (e.g. I want to get the 5 digit number from the second column of the first line). The file opens fine and I'm able to read in the entire thing, but I just don't know how to get certain chunks from a line specifically. Any suggestions? (NOTE: These names and numbers are fictional...)

```
//main cpp file
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("customers.txt");



    return 0;
}

//customers.txt
100007     13153     09067.50     George F. Thompson
579489     21895     00565.48     Keith Y. Graham
711366     93468     04602.64     Isabel F. Anderson
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does it have to be C++?  Or can you use a command line utility?  If you're just trying to solve this particular problem, awk on linux would be your best bet.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you searched StackOverflow for "C++ read parse variable"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some simple hints in your code to help you, you will need to complete the code. But the missing pieces are easy to find at stackoverflow.

```
//main cpp file
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

splitLine(const char* str, vector<string> results){
    // splits str and stores each value in results vector
}

int main()
{
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("customers.txt");
    char buffer[128];
    if(fin.good()){
        while(!fin.eof()){
            fin.getline(buffer, 256);
            cout << buffer << endl;

            vector<string> results;         
            splitLine(buffer, results);
            // now results MUST contain 4 strings, for each 
            // column in a line
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while(!fin.eof())` is really bad style, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Answer (score 1):

Text parsing is not such a trivial thing to implement.

If your format won't change you could try to parse it by yourself, [use random access file access](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/) and use regular expressions to extract the part of the stream that you need, or read a certain quantity of chars.

If you go the regex way, you'll need C++11 or a third party library, like Boost or POCO.

If you can format the text file then you might also want to choose a standard to structure your data, like XML, and use the facilities of that format to extract the information you want. POCO might help you there.

Answer (score 0):

If the columns are separated by whitespace then the second column of the first row is simpy the second token extracted from the stream.

```
std::ifstream input{"customers.txt"}; // Open file input stream.
std::istream_iterator<int> it{input}; // Create iterator to first token.
int number = *std::next(it);          // Advance to next token and dereference.
```